# Share url in facebook messenger from web

Tags: facebook, sharing, facebook-messenger

I would like to share an url from a website (using mobile device) to facebook messenger app.

I tried to use:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html',
});
```

But that does nothing on the mobile device. I also tried:

```
fb://messaging/compose/new
```

That did open the message dialog but I can't find an URI for sharing an url.

I wonder if this is even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Send Dialog, which is not supported on mobile: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog#examples

Alternative for mobile: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger

Comment: The alternative you propose does not compile. I get a Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSDKShareMessengerURLActionButton' error and the code won't compile.  And yes, I am importing the 4.29 sdk and later.

Comment: that is a very specific issue, you should create a new thread for it, including all the relevant code of yours.

Answer (score 27):

This is what you are looking for:

Link:

```
<a href="fb-messenger://share/?link= https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fsharing%2Freference%2Fsend-dialog&app_id=123456789">Send In Messenger</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.open('fb-messenger://share?link=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&app_id=' + encodeURIComponent(app_id));
```

Please note: This will only work on mobile devices. For more information see here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/web

Comment: Is there the same alternative for the desktop web too?
Please mention if you know any.

Comment: it works on mobile if you have FB app installed, is there any solution for non-mobile?

Answer (score 7):

FWIW the following link, clicked on a desktop computer, will allow your user to share the link via Facebook Messenger. You have to replace app-id with the app-id of an arbitrary app of yours, created at developer.faceboook.com:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=[app-id]&link=https://stackoverflow.com&redirect_uri=https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="fb-messenger://share/?link=http://url-you-want-to-share.com&app_id=your-app-id-here">
... 
</a>
```

Does not seem to work on desktop, but I could be wrong.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger